# how to export Accounts with activity history?

Tags: data-loader, account, data-export, activityhistory

I have tried with exporting accounts with activity history using reports.
but, is there any other way to do the same.?

i see there is no correct data exported. could you please suggest on this?

Answer (score -1):

To get the AccountHistory data, first step is to check "Enable Account History" setting for Account Object.

This setting is available at Setup --> Account --> fields --> Click on Set History Tracking button

[image]

Once you enable this setting, you will be able to see data in AccountHistory report.

[image]

Comment: This answer is for Field History Tracking (AccountHistory) object, and not the Activity (Events, Tasks) that @sumit is asking in the question.